# Hazelcast Instance is not active when accessing Distributed Map

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am running an application which is using **Hazelcast in embedded mode**.  Seeing this issue intermittently when accessing the cache , application is throwing Hazelcast instance is not active error.

The code files are as :

```
public DistributedServiceProvider() {
            
        LOGGER.info("DistributedServiceProvider: " + type);

       if ("hazelcast".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            hazelcastInstance = HazelcastConfig.getInstance();
        } else {
            throw new Exception(NOT_CONFIGURED);
        }
    }

    public IMap getMap(String name) { 
        if (hazelcastInstance != null) {
            return hazelcastInstance.getMap(name);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(NOT_INITIALIZED);
    }
```

When running the application and performing some use cases getting following error intermittently.

```
An exception has occurred. Method:: compareIRTrackerRedemptions[null, Fri Apr 30 00:00:00 EDT 2021, Mon May 31 00:00:00 EDT 2021, true]
    Root Cause: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceProxy.getOriginal(HazelcastInstanceProxy.java:315)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceProxy.getMap(HazelcastInstanceProxy.java:95)
        at deshaw.descap.server.cache.provider.DistributedServiceProvider.getMap(DistributedServiceProvider.java:52)
        at deshaw.descap.server.cache.BasicCache.getData(BasicCache.java:100)
        at deshaw.descap.server.cache.FundCaches$FundCache.get(FundCaches.java:185)
```

Comment: Are there any more `com.hazelcast.*` messages in the logs preceding the exception ? Since your `hazelcastInstance` is not null, you would normally only expect this if something shut it down using `Hazelcast.shutdownAll()` or one of the other shutdown mechanisms.

Comment: @NeilStevenson I did explore it from shutdown angle , but unfortunately it was nothing around that.  These are only logs around com.hazelcast.* , the remaining are application stack trace. anything you could suggest in hazelcast config which could make it clear.

Comment: Try setting system property `hazelcast.logging.type` to match the LOGGER you use. If the logging level for `com.hazelcast` is _INFO_ you'll get out more details.